# AttributeError [in fastStructure's chooseK.py]: module 'vars' has no attribute 'insum'

Tags: python, scipy

I've been working with the fastStructure program and am on the step of analyzing model complexity using the provided chooseK.py script. I have been running into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chooseK.py", line 109, in <module>
    bestKs = parse_varQs(files)
  File "chooseK.py", line 54, in parse_varQs
    Q = Q/utils.insum(Q,[1])
AttributeError: module 'vars' has no attribute 'insum'
```

I have run into 'AttributeError' messages in the past and have attempted the solution of renaming files in my working directory that may be shadowing the real module (similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530726/using-numpy-module-object-has-no-attribute-array), but this hasn't fixed anything. Reinstalling Numpy/Scipy/fastStructure has also been a dead end.

Any suggestions are much appreciated! Happy to provide more info as needed.

-A

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did you build the library extensions? The module vars.utils are imported as utils, so the attribute insum is undetected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312470/difference-between-methods-and-attributes-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Could you try loading `fastStructure` via conda?

```
conda create --name faststruc python=3.9 # there can be issues with 3.10
conda activate faststruc
conda install -c bioconda faststructure
```

It will then ask you whether you want to install `numpy` and `scipy` automatically. Furthermore all dependencies are installed and connectivity will have already been tested. You can easily delete everything afterwards by deleting the environment `faststruc` so keeps everything clean.

---

The code in question is here:

https://programtalk.com/python-examples/vars.utils.insum/

Its a `numpy` calculation, what they are doing is navigating Python by leveraging the power of `numpy`, which is very fast.

Code ...

```
bestKs = []
for file in files:
    handle = open(file,'r')
    Q = np.array([map(float,line.strip().split()) for line in handle])
    Q = Q/utils.insum(Q,[1])
    handle.close()
    N = Q.shape[0]
    C = np.cuemsum(np.sort(Q.sum(0))[::-1])
    bestKs.append(np.sum(C<N-1)+1)

return bestKs
```

The code looks good, they know their stuff.